# about mavproxy.py can not get flight control 's data

Tags: server

I have a public ip server, Its **IP** is `34.16.131.0`
I use a `pi` board to send `arducontroller` to it and wish to get information from it.

so in my `pi`

```
mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyAMA0,57600 --out=34.16.131.0:14550
```

in my local machine,

```
mavproxy --master=udpout:34.16.131.0:14550 --out=127.0.0.1:1455
```

but the mission planner can not read anything from the local
who can tell me, how to do it?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Questions for pre-made software may be asked on e.g. https://superuser.com instead.